# Jasmine-jQuery - can you "call through" an event spy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I need to duplicate the functionality of a spy that is called through for an event. I.e., given that there exists: `spyOn(method).and.callThrough()`, does there also exist something like: `spyOnEvent(event).and.triggerThrough()`?

Answer (score 0):

The event acts similarly as a function call, so you would set it up in the same way.

E.g. when you setup your component, and have a function (`onInit`) where you expect another function (`myFunction`) to be called as part of it.

```
// arrange
spyOn(component, 'myFunction');

// act
component.onInit();

// assert
expect(component.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In the same way you can thus setup your events, where the event (`myEvent`) is triggered inside the tested function (`myFunction`):

```
  // arrange
  spyOn(component.myEvent, 'emit');

  // act 
  component.myFunction(); 

  // assert
  expect(component.myEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Only when you have a service has a call that is expected to execute will you normally setup the data, as your test scope requires some return data:

```
spyOn(myService, 'myServiceFunction').and.returnValue(of(true));
```

Alternatively you can set it up as:

```
mockedService.spyOf(x => x.myServiceFunction).and.returnValue(of(true));
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand this answer... 2 things: 1) this doesn't address my root question which is whether the native `spyOnEvent` has a `callThrough` function on it (that has different terminology obviously because I tried that and it didn't work. 2) `returnValue` is not the same as `callThrough`. in my case I specifically need the event to be triggered so that other things in the code are executed. Like... if what you're proposing is a hack work around, then yes we could hack it to make it work, but I'm hoping for a native solution, if it exists